# How to push data from server to client?

Tags: java, http, server, client, server-push

Consider the case where the client makes a HTTP request to server (which is a java application) to get the value X mapped against each file/resource.

The server does some computation to get value X.  It goes in the following way

1. Write the file to the storage device
2. Compute the value X for the file
3. Store it in database

When the client requests value for the file when computing the value X we would respond to the client with some default value some constant value (the X value generation at the server side is going on..)

> If the client requests for the value X when the server is generating X, the server must do the following
>
> 1. Must push the progress state of the computation to the client for every 10% (like 20%, 30%, 50% etc..)
> 2. Must push the value X to the client once the computation gets over.

Please suggest an optimum way to achieve this.

Comment: Which server framework do you use?

Comment: We are using struts framework Donghwan Kim

Comment: Then what about trying Servlet 3's async support? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm